# Find the probability distributions that if $U>X$ for random variables $U$ and $X$ with general distributions, then $V=U-X$ follows distribution of $U$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Assume that random variables $X$ and $U$ follow the general probability distributions $f_X(x)$ and $f_U(u)$. I want to find the $f_U(u)$s that if $U>X$ holds, then $V=U-X$ follows the probability distribution of $U$. In the question I asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4109731/find-the-distribution-function-of-v-u-x-when-x-follows-the-exponential-dis?noredirect=1#comment8496698_4109731), I have shown that such a relation holds for $U$ follows exponential distribution. I want to know for what other probability distributions this relationship exists.

Answer (score 1):

The problem cannot be solved if you do not know the joint denisty $f_{UX}(u,x)$. Given that $U>X$ they cannot be independent thus you need more information in order to derive $f_{UX}$

Once you know the joint density, you can use the defintion of CDF finding

$$F_V(v)=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\left[ \int_x^{x+v}f_{UX}(u,x)du  \right]dx$$

As usual, a drawing can be useful

[image]

Comment: what kind of information i need to simplify this problem?

Comment: @OptimizeLife:  you need the density of $f(x,u)$ of any information that allow you to derive it.

Comment: In fact, I want to know for which class of probability distributions this relationship exists. Even if not all of them, I want to know if there is another probability distribution with this property?