# An argument on exponential distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, exponential-distribution

Based on the question I asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4109731/find-the-distribution-function-of-v-u-x-when-u-follows-the-exponential-dis), if we assume that the independent random variables $U$ and $X$ follow the exponential distribution with parameter $\lambda$ and the general distribution $f_X(x)$, respectively. Therefore, if $U>X>0$, then $V=U-X$ is follows exponential distribution with parameter $\lambda$. Now suppose the random variable $W$ and $W'$ is defined as follows:
$$W=U-X+X$$
therefore:
$$W'=Q+X$$

where $Q$ is a random variable follows exponential distribution with parameter $\lambda$. Can we say that the probability distribution of $W$ is equal to $W'$ and therefore follows the exponential distribution with parameter $\lambda$?

If not, what is the problem with my argument?

Comment: Your random variables do not exist. You cannot have $U,X$ independent with $U$ exponential and $U >X$ a.s.

Comment: Why? Suppose $U$ and $X$ are i.i.d random variables with exponential distribution and parameter $\lambda$. we also know that $U$ is greater than $X$

Comment: if we know that $U$ is greater than $X$, then $U$ and $X$ depend on each other.

Comment: You have been posting many questions like this where the r.v.'s do not even exist.

Comment: I do not know how you view the problem. Maybe I did not ask the question correctly. But the point that makes perfect sense is that if the two variables $X$ and $U$ are independent, why should the conditional relation on them make the variables themselves interdependent? I know that the defined condition makes the result dependent, but why should the variables themselves be dependent?

Answer (score -1):

If $P(U>X)=1$ then $\int P(X<u)\lambda e^{-\lambda x} dx=1$. Since $P(X<u) \leq 1$ this implies that $P(X<u)=1$ a.e. (w.r.t Lebesgue measure). But this is implies that $P(X \leq 0)=1$. So you r random varbles do not exist.

Intuitively an inequality like $U>X$ between r.v.'s destroys independence.

Comment: Can someone tell why this is downvoted? I think anyone with basic knowledge of Probability Theory with agree with this answer.

Comment: The arguments I have made on various questions have been published in very authoritative articles(e.g IEEE Transactions). I will post links to articles that have used the same argument a few more times. I have also done various simulations and the simulation results are consistent with the results of the mathematical model. I do not know why the condition of being larger should make the random variables themselves dependent?

Comment: You took the time to give this answer and I am really grateful